# PDF opening event in IOS app for rendered URL on UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I am using a `UIWebView` control and opening a web page URL on it in landscape mode only. In this URL on a particular event a PDF is getting opened. This time the PDF is not getting opened  properly (it always shows only first page of the PDF file), and in the Output window i am getting "flatedecode decoding error".

Is there any way so that my application can catch that PDF opening event, and I can open the PDf in Safari or some other browser rather than `UIWebView`?

Or is there any way in Phonegap to achieve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can save PDF in your document directory by using this code

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *cachePath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
BOOL isDir = NO;
NSError *error;
//You must check if this directory exist every time
if (! [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:cachePath isDirectory:&isDir] && isDir   == NO)
{
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:cachePath withIntermediateDirectories:NO attributes:nil error:&error];
}
NSString *filePath = [cachePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"QRScanner.pdf"];
//webView.request.URL contains current URL of UIWebView, don't forget to set outlet for it
NSData *pdfFile = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:webView.request.URL];
if(pdfFile)
{
    [AppDelegate obj_appDelegate].Alertview.hidden = YES;
    [[AppDelegate obj_appDelegate].activity stopAnimating];
}
[pdfFile writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you only need a way to find out whether the specific link opening the PDF is clicked or not?

Make sure you make your viewcontroller a delegate for the webview. Then implement this method

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

**navigationType** will be **UIWebViewNavigationTypeLinkClicked**  when a new page loads on link click.

**request** will tell you the URL being opened and you can listen if the URL is one of your PDF. If it is then you can handle it in the method however you want to - download it and open in another web view or open in safari.

More details [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWebViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).